# Show/hide script does not work

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I dont know whats wrong with my script. Why .inside disappear if I hovering it? I want it to be visible if is .inside hovered.

```
<ul class="drop">
    <li class="thumb">
        Arival
        <ul class="inside">
            <li>První</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Some jquery here:

```
$("li.thumb").hover(
    function() { $(this).children().show(); },
    function() { $(this).children().hide(); }
);
```

Working on http://jsfiddle.net/0s7gd6g3/

Comment: It's not working because as soon as you move away from "Arival" the sub menus disappear so you have no chance of reaching them. I think you might need to restructure how you want this to work

Comment: I think you need `$(this).children('.inside')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".drop").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('.inside').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.inside').hide();
    }
);
```

If you want a jQuery fix, this will do it for you. Just changed the element that triggers the hide/show

Comment: This is not very good suggestion as there can be multiple nested submenus all with the class `.inside`.

Comment: But with the situation OP has put forward, this is a valid solution

Answer (score 0):

Nested submenu disappears because there is a gap between `li.thumb` and `ul.inside` element. When the mouse is over this area submenu hides of course because .thumb is no longer hovered and `.inside` is positioned absolutely.

To fix it you can decrease `top` position of the submenu and instead move it vertically with padding-top value:

```
.inside {
    border: 1px white solid;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 190px;
    top: 37px;
    left: -2px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/0s7gd6g3/8/

Also you don't really need javascript in this case as it's simple and more effective CSS usecase:

```
li.thumb:hover .inside {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the height of the thumb div so that when you hover it remains there otherwise it will be confined to that space.

So add this class:

```
.thumb {
    height:100px
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0s7gd6g3/7/)